# Is this the correct gist of how to use Django Simple JWT?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The client will be Android

- Use username and password via POST to /thetokenurl to get access and refresh token, store access and refresh token in local storage
- Use token in auth header for any API call to protected endpoint
- Whenever frontend needs API call, you always have to do if/else work to check if the response say something about token being expired, and if its expired, then use the refresh token from local storage to get a new access token, and then store new access token in local storage and then make the API call to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is one way of doing it, e.g using interceptors on the client/middleware to check expiration either before making a request (if there are time stamps set) or checking the responses. You would then refresh if needed. Keep in mind that you might also want to incorporate a queue to make sure that failed requests are still seen as successful to the user (e.g an expired request which successfully refreshes).

Comment: Thank you.  The last part you mentioned. Are you saying that I should notify the user if the clients token was expired and then refreshed?

Comment: No, you ideally want to hide it from the user, that's why you would implement a queue to where failed requests can be retried if the cookie refresh succeeded. Unless you need to log them out, then you would notify them and say "hey, due to security reasons we logged you out". Although that's usually only the case if the user is idle and the app has security requirements. This is the balance between UX and security. There are plenty of articles on how to handle JWT refreshing so I would suggest reading up on it, it's a common design challenge.